# How to choose between development and production firebase project based on build flavours?

Tags: firebase, flutter

In native development I switch my application between firebase production and development project depending on build "flavour".

On Android I put `google-services.json` inside the folder

```
<ProjectDir>/app/src/<BuildFlavour>
```

Where `BuildFlavour` could be, for example, `debug` or `release`.

So that could be easily done also for a Flutter project. Indeed I see:

```
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/shadowsheep/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app_test_fcm_messaging/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json
```

On iOS I'll do it this way instead:

```
        NSString *googleFirebaseJsonFileName = @"GoogleService-Info";
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Development mode.");
        googleFirebaseJsonFileName = @"GoogleService-Info-Debug";
#else
        NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Production mode.");
#endif
        NSLog(@"%@", googleFirebaseJsonFileName);
        NSString *googleFirebaseJsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                pathForResource:googleFirebaseJsonFileName
                                                ofType:@"plist"];
        NSLog(@"%@", googleFirebaseJsonFilePath);

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
        FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc]
                               initWithContentsOfFile:googleFirebaseJsonFilePath];
        [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

How can I achieve this in Flutter the right way for iOS project? I've gotta put this exact code inside `AppDelegate` here?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // I've to init Firebase here the same way?
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I've done like that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSString *googleFirebaseJsonFileName = @"GoogleService-Info";
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Development mode.");
    googleFirebaseJsonFileName = @"GoogleService-Info-Debug";

    NSLog(@"%@", googleFirebaseJsonFileName);
    NSString *googleFirebaseJsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                            pathForResource:googleFirebaseJsonFileName
                                            ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"%@", googleFirebaseJsonFilePath);

    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc]
                           initWithContentsOfFile:googleFirebaseJsonFilePath];
    if ([FIRApp defaultApp]) {
        NSLog(@"Firebase already configured!");
        [[FIRApp defaultApp]
         deleteApp:^(BOOL success) {
             if (success) {
                 NSLog(@"Reconfigure Firebase");
                 [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
             }
         }];
    } else {
        [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
    }
#else
    NSLog(@"[FIREBASE] Production mode.");
#endif

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have flavours in Flutter by having different entry points.

For example you can have an enum like this:

> enum BuildConfig {
>     development,
>     production,
>   }

And you can have two entry files for your application.

One for production:

> main_production.dart

Which at some point it inits a constant somewhere like:

> buildConfig = BuildConfig.production;

And another file for development:

> main_dev.dart

Which will init the constant like:

> buildConfig = BuildConfig.development;

You can start your app using the `-t` flag (for `target`)

> flutter run -t lib/main_production.dart

In this context the `buildConfig` var will have the value `BuildConfig.production`.

I highly recommend checking out [this article](https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36) for more info.

Based in this you can choose what Firebase project to init.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the title was a bit misleading (I hope the post's body wasn't), but I was not looking for Flutter flavours (even if it could be a hot topic) but a way to automatically switch between firebase project the easy way. I think that for what I wanna achieve my solution it's easier. I don't know if there's an easier one.