# How to change $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, android-productflavors

I am build different flavor of Flutter app with different Firebase environment (development and production). I need set different bundle ID for development and production in Xcode for iOS apps.

I am use schemes to configure the different flavor (in Build Settings I add environment value for every configuration).

But I have big issue with change `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`. I need add suffix `.development` to normal app id for development app id.

I have try follow [this method](https://medium.com/@kavithakumarasamy89/xcode-build-settings-user-defined-settings-manage-multiple-environments-with-single-target-3e5c1a307999)(use User Defined Settings) and change `info.plist` to get variable from User Defined Settings but it not work.

Error is:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Application
>   “$(EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID)" is unknown to FrontBoard.

So it seem when pass in User Defined Setting it is not interpolate correct.

I have also try mix method of add default `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` and User Defined Settings. For example: `com.example.app$(EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID)` where `EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID` = `.development`

I also try reference User Defined Setting `$(EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID)` by direct add it  to Bundle Identifier in Target General tab under ‘Identity’. But this then change to : `-- EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID-`

I have also try in `info.plist` use `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)$(EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID)` for Bundle Identifier value. But this give similar error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Application
>   “com.example.app$(EXAMPLE_BUNDLE_ID)" is unknown to FrontBoard.

Again this look like interpolation issue.

Anyone know solution? I have look but cannot find answer.

This easy for android because just use `applicationIdSuffix ".development”` in `productFlavors`. But I cannot find way like this for Xcode.

Answer (score 22):

Do you need to have different `package name` (Android) and `bundle id` (iOS) because you need to use `Firebase Auth` plugin?

In this case for iOS project you shold consider using `PlistBuddy` and you could set it adding a `Run Script` in your `XCode build phases` like that

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.example.developmento.appName" "$PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
echo "Changed bundle id for developement $PROJECT_DIR/Runner/Info.plist"
else
echo "Nothing to do"
fi
```

[image]

Anyway if you don't use `Firebase Auth`, you can have the same bundle id in different firebase projects.

If you need then to differenziate firebase projects file between staging and production, you could have a look here:

[How to choose between development and production firebase project based on build flavours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018791/how-to-choose-between-development-and-production-firebase-project-based-on-build/54021418#54021418)

**UPDATE**

So following OP chat, knowing that he's following this [tutorial](https://www.tengio.com/blog/multiple-firebase-environments-with-flutter/) to setup `flutter flavors` I've tryed myself to see where we were stuck.

Starting point is the following:

- **Two** `Firebase project`
- Use of `Firebase Auth` module (so the need to change the bundle id between projects)
- And of course two different `GoogleService-Info.plist`

I start with Xcode `bundle id` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` set to production (just an option)

[image]

Then I've save both `GoogleServices-Info-staging.plist` and `GoogleServices-Info-production.plist` save in my ios/Runner folder

[image]

Then I setup this build script before the script for `Compile Sources`

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-Runner-staging" ]; then 

echo "Setting up staging firebase environment"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.example.staging.flutterAppAuthFlavours" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Info.plist"
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info-staging.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist" 
echo "$(date) staging flavour - Configuration: ${CONFIGURATION}" > "${PROJECT_DIR}/environment.txt"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-Runner-production" ]; then 

echo "Setting up production firebase environment"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.example.flutterAppAuthFlavours" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Info.plist" 
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info-production.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"
echo "$(date) production flavour - Configuration:  ${CONFIGURATION}" > "${PROJECT_DIR}/environment.txt"

fi
```

And I called it `Setup Firebase Environment` (you can call it what you want)

[image]

This script store also some logs (with timestamp) in a file called `environment.txt` inside `ios` folder in order to easy check what xcode build has done

[image]

And now about `Schemes` and `Build Configurations`:

I've done **two** `Build Configuration` that are the exact copy of my `Debug Build Configuration` and I called them

[image]

- `Debug-Runner-staging`
- `Debug-Runner-production`

The rule of thumb is to name the build configurations as `'Debug-<your flavor>'` and you need to **have a scheme for every flavors** you have, so I have these:

- `Runner-staging` whose Run calls *Debug-Runner-staging* build configuration
- `Runner-production` whose Run calls *Debug-Runner-production* build configuration

[image]

[image]

So now if I call `flutter run --flavor Debug-staging` I have a build that runs on my *staging* firebase project.

and if I call `flutter run --flavor Debug-production` I have a build that runs on my *production* firebase project.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Just for completness you could change bundle id also here:

[image]

Anyway it seems that there's a ***strange behavior*** that once you build a `flavour` a second time `flutter` command *build correctly the flavor but run the previos build flavor*.

As building with `XCode` and switching with schemes all works as expected (even the run of the right application) I guess that this could be a flutter command issue. So I suggest you trying file an issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) linking also this SO question/answer.

**UPDATE 3**

After a bit of intel I've found that `flutter tools` set the applicaiton launching environment before building the project. So when we change `CFBundleIdentifier` inside `Info.plist` the first time, the second time we launch `flutter run` it takes the previous modified value and try launching this bundle id while during build we are changing it because we are building a different variant.

A possible solution could be to launch a **script** that change the `CFBundleIdentifier` inside `Info.plist` before calling `fluetter run`.

For example starting with a `Info.plist` with a production bundle id of `com.example.flutterAppAuthFlavours` we could do something like that

[image]

[image]

Here I’ve used `sed` command just to think different, but you could call always our belowed `PlistBuddy` to make the change before calling `flutter run`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes is because I use `Firebase Auth` for Google sign in. I have try you suggestion use `PlistBuddy` but still not work.  If leave build script last get error: `The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist’, or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options`
I have check `GoogleService-Info.plist` and it have correct Bundle ID. I also check in Xcode and it have correct bundle ID. So I confused. Bundle ID in Xcode `info.plist` match Bundle ID in `GoogleService-Info.plist` but have this error message.

Comment: Thanks for update! But still have issue and strange behaviour. Maybe this can explain something. For example when run `flutter run --flavor development` and then after quit and run `flutter run --flavor production` it build correct app but open wrong one. Maybe this why I get error : `The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist’`? Maybe there is problem with way we are change bundle ID?

Comment: @FlutterFirebase if you follow my guide and follow my road all works fine. As you can see I personally tested it. No errors man. Check your setup and put logs. Try to follow my example as straight as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I follow exact. It work sometime no error! but when do more `run` it open wrong app after build. Try change app name for different bundle so can see.

Comment: @FlutterFirebase really? Try doing a `flutter clean` and `flutter stop` before your `flutter run`.

Comment: Yes I have try but still error: `The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist’`

Comment: @FlutterFirebase That’s strange. It doesn’t happen to me.

Comment: Why must specify build config in every scheme? From script it will copy correct GoogleService-Info.plist file and make correct change to `CFBundleIdentifier`.

Comment: @FlutterFirebase Hey bro, look [here](https://youtu.be/SjUiupo4tVw). As you can see I get the error you get **only** when I have a *misconfiguration*, otherwise all works as expected. As for your question regarding specifying a build config in every scheme, that's not true. Both `scheme` and `configs` are project level configuration. Scheme has actions like `build/run/archive/profile` etc. and you can setup a different cofiguration to each action. I suggest you to study a little more this `XCode` topics in order to find out your misconfiguration.

Comment: @FlutterFirebase I had the same problem: `The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist’, or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options I have check GoogleService-Info.plist`. I solved it with placing `GoogleService-Info.plist` in `Runner` folder. After running the script in `Building Phases` it gets replaced and everything works OK.